# ReactGA not working for G type tracking Id

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am trying to implement google analytics in my reaact application. But does give any page hit in analytics dashboard.

Here is the implementation:
In App.js:

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
 componentDidMount() {
    ReactGA.initialize("G-QBQXxxxxx");
    ReactGA.pageview("/")
  }
```

Anything wrong in my implementation ?

Answer (score 12):

Based on [react-ga docs](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#react-google-analytics-module), it is designed to work with **Universal Analytics** which was the latest version of Google Analytics until Oct 14, 2020. Since then, GA-4 is the default property type in Google Analytics. You need to create a property of type **Universal Analytics**. To do so, go to Google Analytics Home page and go to **Admin**.

[image]

Select the **Account** that you want to add a **Property** to and click on **Create Property**.

[image]

Now you proceed to **Property setup** page. (Also you could have created a new **Account** and after setting its name in the second step you would have seen **Property Setup**). Then click on **Show advanced options**.

[image]

Enable **Create a Universal Analytics property** and select one of the available options. If you select **Create both a Google Analytics 4 and a Universal Analytics property**, you will have two different properties one having a *MEASUREMENT ID* like `GA-XXXXXXXXXX` and another having a *Tracking ID* like `UA-XXXXXXXXXX`. Use the *Tracking ID* instead of *MEASUREMENT ID*.

[image]

Comment: what is the advantage of choosing both options(Google Analytics 4 and Universal Analytics property)?

Comment: Then you can track your app stats using both GA4 and UAT. I mean you can use both Measurement ID (starting with "G-") and Tracking ID (starting with "UA-") for the same app. Some libraries may require "G-" while some others require "UA-". When you have both of them in your Google Analytics account for the same app, you'll have both options in your hand.

Answer (score 2):

The **Universal Analytics id** its going to be desappear in 2023 July 1° and the **react-ga** is outdated, because only works with UA code.

For this reason, you can use **[react-ga4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4)**, and you can use the **Measurement ID** (which begins with "G-")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Measurement ID (which begins with "G-"), set up a Universal Analytics ("Web") property (Universal Analytics properties have views instead of data streams), you have a Tracking ID (which begins with "UA-"), and then

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
componentDidMount() {
    ReactGA.initialize("UA-XXXXXXXX");
    ReactGA.pageview("/")
  }
```

It works just fine